# Laravel 5: build URL with custom parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application in which you can choose between multiple customers.
Choosing a customer will generate following URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/customer/CUSTOMER_NAME
```

From there on, I would like to choose a specific sub-page (e.g.: the support page)

How do I generate the following link:

```
http://localhost:8000/customer/CUSTOMER_NAME/support
```

So far, I always lose my CUSTOMER_NAME parameter, and I do not know how to keep it.

The framework I use is Laravel 5.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: if you have code, please include it as code in the question, not as an image.

Comment: vote up for descriptive question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall do this by passing the url param to the view by

I believe you have something like this in your route

`Route::get('customer/{id}', 'yourController@yourFunctionName');`

Then, in your controller, you may have

```
public function yourFunctionName($id)
{
    return view('yourViewName')->with('id', $id);
}
```

Then from your view can simply do this to generate a [url](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters) like this

```
<a href="customer/{id}/support">Click here</a>
```

To have the url like below

`http://yourprojectname/customer/18/support`

**Advice :** Use the Primary key or any unique field rather than using name to avoid some future issues.

Also you shall use helpers to generate url's

Comment: Thanks Sulthan Allaudeen! (Both for the answer and the advice) ... @Domysee: I'll take your remark of code as an image into account next time!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes)?

```
Route::get('customer/{name}', ['as' => 'customer.index', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@index']);
```

You could set up a new route like this:

```
Route::get('customer/{name}/support', ['as' => 'customer.support', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@support']);
```

with a method for the support section

```
public function support($name) {
    return view('customer.support', [
        'name' => $name,
    ]);
}
```

And in your layout you can link to the route.

```
<a href="{{ route('customer.support', $name) }}">Support</a>
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the input! I'm rather new to Laravel, so for now I'll stick with Sulthan's answer. However, I will look into those named routes, they look interesting!

Comment: Vote up for clear answer and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ route('pages.home', $array_of_custom_params) }}
```

This will generate the link: